# Why do i get unexpected answer in Prolog. List, multiply, recursion

Tags: list, recursion, prolog, multiplication

I have to display all elements in lists as is shown in example.
`Element: el, List: L. [L1el1, L2el1], [L1el2, L2el1], [L1el3, L2el1]...`
I am using `multiply/3` predecate to run program and `multiply/4` for recursion. It restores 'L1' from 'Tmp' when it gets empty (only if L2 is not empty. Otherwise, terminate recursion).

Abstract example:

```
for element l in List1 {
    for element k in List2 {
        print([k, l]);
    }
}
```

my_code.pl

```
multiply(L1, L2, X):-
    multiply(L1, L2, L1, X).

multiply(X, [], _, X).

multiply([], [_|T], Tmp, X):-
    multiply(Tmp, T, Tmp, X),!.

multiply([H|T], [H1|T1], Tmp, [[H,H1]|X]):-
    multiply(T, [H1|T1], Tmp, X).
```

Expected:

```
?- multiply([1,2,3], [a,b], X).
X = [[1, a], [2, a], [3, a], [1, b], [2, b], [3, b]].
```

What did I get:

```
?- multiply([1,2,3], [a,b], X).
X = [[1, a], [2, a], [3, a], [1, b], [2, b], [3, b], 1, 2, 3].
```

How to get expected result modifying this code a bit. **Without using built-in predicates!**

Why L1 appears at the end of X? how to fix it?

Comment: The problem occurs in your 2nd clause: `multiply(X, [], _, X).`. This clause will *succeed* with `X = [1,2,3]` right from the start, and so `[1, 2, 3]` becomes the tail of whatever result is generated. Think through what your predicate *means semantically* and make sure your rules make sense.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The problem was in the `multiply/4` with recursion exiting condition.

```
    multiply(X, [_|X], _, X).
```